# Make Camel xslt component use xml catalogs for resolving DTDs

Tags: apache-camel

We use the camel xslt component to transform a xhtml file.
But for transforming the file, the used XMLReader downloads the xhtml dtd from the w3c website.

Is it possible, to tell the xslt component, to configure the xml reader to use local version (e.g. by using xml catalogs)?

Comment: This is also being discussed here: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Make-xslt-component-not-to-validate-dtd-s-or-use-local-copy-tp5727789.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way, using a processor, that creates a XMLReader using the CatalogResolver and puts a SAXSource using this xmlReader into the exchange.

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);

    XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    xmlReader.setEntityResolver(new CatalogResolver());
    exchange.getIn().setBody(new SAXSource(xmlReader, new InputSource(inputStream)));
}
```

The Transformer used by the xsltComponent will then use this xmlReader.